# How to set our site as a Referrals site in google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, referrals

I was studying google analytics since last one week and found that there are found that there are four category in which audience coming on your site falls.
Referral
Social
Direct
Organic

Now I had redirected my one site to another then why it doesn't shows as a referral site?

How can I set my site as a referral site when any one clicks on their site link from my site?

Comment: How did you "redirect" ? I don't think a 301 or 302 redirect would register as a referrer.

Comment: Yes that I have checked and not working so asking any other possible ways to get as organic or direct visits than referral one.

I redirected directly through cpanel